# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException while accessing string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to split the string and match it with constant strings. I got the address string I want to check the sender for that I tried to split the strings. For that I tried this way.

```
if (cursor != null) {
 cursor.moveToFirst();
 try {
  while (!cursor.isAfterLast() && !cursor.isBeforeFirst()) {
   String messageAddress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
   if (isCorporateMessage(messageAddress)) {
    String matchString[] = messageAddress.split("-");
    if (matchString[0].length() == 2) { //getting exception here I guess
     if (matchString[1].toUpperCase().contains("OLA")) {
      isFrom = 1;
     } else if (matchString[1].toUpperCase().contains("UBR")) {
      isFrom = 2;
     } else if (matchString[1].toUpperCase().contains("BK")) {
      isFrom = 3;
     } else if (Utils.isBankMessage(matchString[1].toUpperCase())) {
      isFrom = 3;
     } else if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toUpperCase().contains("BANK")) {
      isFrom = 3;
     } else if (matchString[1].toUpperCase().contains("PAYTM")) {
      isFrom = 4;
     } else if (matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("VK-iPaytm") || matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("AD-IPAYTM")) {
      isFrom = 4;
     } else {
      isFrom = 5;
     }
     // check if message has otp or not
     String smsBody = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
     if (!Utils.isContainAnyTypeOfCode(smsBody)) {

      SMSModel sms = new SMSModel();

      sms.setId(messageAddress);
      sms.setBody(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
      sms.setAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());


      sms.setType(String.valueOf(isFrom));
      long date = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("date"));

      SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy", Locale.ENGLISH);
      String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(date));
      sms.setDate(dateString);

      if (isFrom > 0) {
       CounterHolder.smsModelArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());

       if (!datePreference.getBoolean("firstDump", false)) {

        sms.setBody(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
        CounterHolder.smsPromArrayList.add(sms);

        Log.d("firstDump", "Processed");

       } else if (datePreference.getBoolean("firstDump", false)) {
        SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

        if (Utils.isLatestSMS(context, fmtOut.format(new Date(date)))) {
         Log.d("sms", "after first dump");

         sms.setBody(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
         CounterHolder.smsPromArrayList.add(sms);
        } else {
         Log.d("sms", "before first dump");
        }
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
   cursor.moveToNext();
  }

  cursor.close();
  Log.d("myapp", "Count of sms" + CounterHolder.smsPromArrayList.size());

  return true;

 } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Now, its throwing java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2 exception. How can I split the strings and match without getting the exception?

Please help. Thank You..

Comment: what is your string?

Comment: string is BX-262735 @V-rundPuro-hit

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: `matchString[2]` - maybe this should be `matchString[1]`

Comment: there will be only 2 indexes `matchString[0]` and `matchString[1]` and you are tying to access third index `matchString[2]`

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2 this is the exception I get. @Stultuske

Comment: error at `matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("VK-iPaytm")`

Comment: else if (matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("VK-iPaytm") || matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("AD-IPAYTM")) {
                                isFrom = 4;
                            }
this is incorrect matchString[2] not valid for array of two element.

Comment: wait, you are splitting your array with "-", so `matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("VK-iPaytm")` this will never return true. plus you are converting in to upercase and "VK-iPaytm" has lowercase latters so there will be problem too. (just side problem you might face later on)

Answer (score 2):

When accessing array index you have to make sure that index is valid. If your address is `BX-262735` then your array size is 2. So check valid array index before using it.

```
  if ( matchString.length > 2 &&  matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("some string") ) {
     //.....
   }
```

Comment: }
                                else if (matchString.length > 2 && matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("VK-iPaytm") || matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("AD-IPAYTM"))  I tried this still getting same exception

Answer (score 1):

`"BX-262735 with"` split on `"-"` will result in an array with two elements, yet with `matchString[2]`

You are trying to access a third element of that array. That is what your error message is telling you.

Answer (score 1):

change like this or check your array splits correctly or not based on your concept

```
else if (matchString.length > 2 &&   
matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("VK-iPaytm") || 
matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("AD-IPAYTM")) {
isFrom = 4;
}
```

Comment: }
                                else if (matchString.length > 2 && matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("VK-iPaytm") || matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("AD-IPAYTM"))  i tried this still getting same exception

Comment: what exception ?

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2 this one

Comment: i think problem not in that  else if ...best you remove that line and check its working or not..

Comment: @sasikumar i believe it should be like `if (matchString.length > 2 && (
matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("VK-iPaytm") || 
matchString[2].toUpperCase().contains("AD-IPAYTM")))` wrap or condition inside "()'

Comment: if first condition fails means its wont check next in 'and' condition